# axis2 generating only callbackhandler and stub

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-axis, axis

i'm confused why axis2 is generating only callbackHandler class ans stub classe and the other classes are not there i'm using bottom up approche and my version of axis is 1.6.2 thank you

Comment: What other classes are you looking for? Could you show us how exactly you're running the code generator tool? Ie, what command line parameters are you using with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need only these two classes to crate a call to web service from your custom code. There are methods you can call to execute functions in web service. Refer below tutorial for creating client.

https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html#createclients

All other required axis2 calsses (which are being used used by above callbackHandler and stub) will be taken from axis2 jar files you add to your class path.

Make sure you add jar files in /lib folder to your project classpath to run the program without any error.